# Delete multiple columns using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a database with 6037 space-separated columns and 450 rows like the one below:

```
1807 1452 1598 1 6.655713  A B A B ... 0 
1808 1452 1763 1 9.362033  0 0 A B ... A 
1809 1452 1527 2 6.728534  A B A A ... B 
1810 1452 1367 2 9.4055  A B A A B ... A 
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1812 1452 1258 1 6.363032  0 0 A B ... B
```

I want to get a new database with only the first 676 columns.

Preferably, some form that uses `awk` or `sed` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the column delimiter in your file is a single character, e.g. a space, `cut` can do that easily:

```bsh
cut -d' ' -f-676 <in >out
```

This prints only the space-separated columns from the first to the 676th.

If you need e.g. every whitespace character to count as a delimiter, a `sed` solution is:

```bsh
sed -r 's/\s+\S+//677g' <in >out
```

This replaces every column (= at least one whitespace character followed by at least one non-whitespace character) beginning with the 677th with nothing. Using character groups you can specify any set of delimiters you need, e.g. for “4”, “#” and “K”:

```bsh
sed -r 's/[4#K]+[^4#K]+//677g' <in >out
```

For a *reasonable* `awk` approach kindly refer to [steeldriver’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127680/507051), but here is another one looping over the columns and only printing them (separated by `FS`) if their number is <= 676:

```bsh
awk '{for (i=1;i<=676;i++) {printf (i==1?"":FS)$i}; print ""}' <in >out
```

For a character group you have to specify the output field separator for the output, e.g. for `[4#K]` and `"sep"`:

```bsh
awk -F'[4#K]' '{for (i=1;i<=676;i++) {printf (i==1?"":"sep")$i}; print ""}' <in >out
```

Comment: Delimiter "squeezing" can also be done with `tr -s ' '`

Answer (score 6):

For a single-character delimiter (such as space or comma) I would recommend using the `cut` command over either `awk` or `sed`.

However since you asked about `awk` specifically, I *think* a reasonable way to do it would be to decrement the field count:

```
awk -v last=676 '{NF = last} 1' datafile
```

*Tested in GNU Awk (`gawk`) and `mawk`*.

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
mlr --nidx --fs ' ' --repifs cat inputFile.csv | cut -d ' ' -f-2
```

In this way with [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)/`mlr` you manage field separators (if you have more than one spaces, they become one per field), and with cut you extract (in my example) the first two fields.

From

```
1807   1452 1598  1 6.655713  A B A B
1808 1452 1763 1  9.362033  0 0 A B
1809 1452 1527 2 6.728534  A B   A A
1810 1452 1367 2 9.4055  A B A A B
```

to

```
1807 1452
1808 1452
1809 1452
1810 1452
```

Some notes about Miller options:

- `--nidx` is to set the format; this is a generic index-numbered table (the first field is 1, the second is 2, ecc..);
- `--fs` to set the separator (here is a space);
- `--repifs` means that multiple successive occurrences of the field separator count as one
- `cat` passes input records directly to output.